# How to ensure stored procedure finishes before building dataset in Report Builder 3.0?

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssis, reportbuilder

I want to refresh a table using a SSIS package every time the user runs a report built out of Report Builder 3.0, so I've created a SSIS job and call `sp_start_job` from Report Builder as a stored procedure to invoke this job.

This all works fine, but the report doesn't wait for the job to finish before populating the dataset (I can tell because I have a "last refresh date" column in my table).

Is there a way to make sure the job finishes before the data gets loaded into the report itself?

**Edit:** So I decided to try calling the job and waiting before the `SELECT` statement like this:

```
USE msdb;

EXECUTE dbo.sp_start_job N'CUBE - IS Inventory Report Refresh'

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:25'

USE OtherDatabase;

SELECT  ...
```

but the timestamp is still showing an older date. The SSIS job runs in 17 seconds (from the history logs), so waiting for 25 seconds before I select from the table should be plenty... does anyone have insight on why this is happening?

When I run the query in Management Studio, the table returned shows the right timestamp, so I'm thinking it might be a Report Builder issue (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And that'd be expected. Starting a job is an asynchronous call so once it's started, control returns back to the caller. You'd then need to start polling the sys job tables to see whether the job is currently executing. You could do that in the same proc call and once the job has hit a terminal state (completed, failed) you could then return your dataset to the user. That would answer your question but goodness, that could get ugly.

Is there no way to perform the ETL prior to people using the report?

Comment: The users wanted a way to get up-to-date data out of a SharePoint list which the report is based off of. Because of the complexity of the report, and because I've heard that it was not good practice to touch the SharePoint tables directly, I decided the best way to do it was by importing it into a table and do some T-SQL magic to massage the data.

Comment: Not sure if I actually want to poll the sys job tables, but out of curiosity, how would you do that in Report Builder?

Comment: My assumption on how you implemented this is the proc that kicks off the agent job also returns data to the user? Given that assumption, it'd be a while loop between the `EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_start_job somejob` step and the select statement that actually returns data.